# Google Tag Manager - Tag Firing After Another Tag

Tags: javascript, jquery, html, google-analytics, google-tag-manager

I am having a trouble firing a tag after another tag has been fired.
I currently have "GA - Event Translate Click" & "GA - Event - Reader Google Translate Scroll Tracking".

"GA - Event Translate Click" tag currently fires after onChange event happens (when user click on Google Translator Widget on the page) and it is being placed under "gtm.change" event in the Google Tag Manager.

"GA - Event - Reader Google Translate Scroll Tracking" tag currently fires when the page is loaded and it is being placed under "ceScrollTracking" event in the Google Tag Manager.

I would like "GA - Event - Reader Google Translate Scroll Tracking" tag to be fired and placed in the "ceScrollTracking" event in the Google Tag Manager after "GA - Event Translate Click" tag is being fired.

I have attached screenshots of how it looks like in the Google Tag Manager debugger.

Could anyone please help me with this issue?

[image: GA - Event Reader Google Translate Scroll Tracking Tag]
[image: Click - Google Translate - Reader - FULL Trigger]

Comment: Can you please explain what this event listener is doing "ceScrollTracking"? When user is scrolling the page? And what is the purpose of this tag ""GA - Event - Reader Google Translate Scroll Tracking""?

Comment: @VictorLeontyev First of all, thank you very much for your interest in this question. The purpose of the event listener, "ceScrollTracking" is to calculate the scroll depth when user is scrolling the page. For example, if the user has scrolled half way to the bottom of the page, it would show me "50%".

Comment: @VictorLeontyev The purpose of "GA - Event - Reader Google Translate Scroll Tracking" is to calculate the scroll depth of the user scrolling after the page has been translated through the Google Translator Widget on the page. 

I would like this, "GA - Event - Reader Google Translate Scroll Tracking" to be fired after "GA - Event - Google Translate Click", which will be fired when the Google Translator Widget on the page is being clicked.

I hope this answers your question.

Comment: And can you please add code, how you triggering this tags, because problem in triggers

Comment: @VictorLeontyev Thank you very much for your response. I have uploaded the screenshots of the Trigger and the Tag that is currently being connected. For the "advanced settings" in the tag, I currently do not have anything in there except "Tag firing options" being set to "Once per event".

Comment: How you sending "DL - Reader Page Type"  ?